# Open new Terminal in same SSH session

Tags: terminal, ssh

Is there a way to open a new Terminal in an existing SSH session?  I am logged into a remote system and have a special session that I have to request and wait to receive.  I know I can then use the "xterm &" command to open multiple xterm windows within that session, but xterm behaves differently from OSX's built-in Terminal.  Is there a way to open multiple Terminal windows within the existing SSH session?

Comment: tmux is available through homebrew haven't used it myself tho... https://tmux.github.io/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, you can reuse exiting ssh connection and open ssh in whatever terminal you like. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20410383/151019) to a StackOverflow question for details:

> If you open the first connection with -M:
>
> ```
> ssh -M $REMOTEHOST
> ```
>
> subsequent connections to $REMOTEHOST will "piggyback" on the
>   connection established by the master ssh. Most noticeably, further
>   authentication is not required. See man ssh_config under
>   "ControlMaster" for more details. Use -S to specify the path to the
>   shared socket; I'm not sure what the default is, because I configure
>   connection sharing using the configuration file instead.
>
> In my .ssh/config file, I have the following lines:
>
> ```
> host *
>   ControlMaster auto
>   ControlPath ~/.ssh/ssh_mux_%h_%p_%r
> ```
>
> This way, I don't have to remember to use -M or -S; ssh figures out if
>   a sharable connection already exists for the host/port/username
>   combination and uses that if possible.